# Running WPF application published on Citrix

Tags: wpf, citrix

I am running a WPF 4.0 application which is published on Citrix. We have different machines and most of them work fine while trying to access the application, however if I run it on Win XP where I have local admin rights nothing but a window frame with title bar shows up. Same application is working fine if a user does not have local admin rights.

We had a similar issue when Citrix servers were running Win Server 2003 for which I found a fix: KB955692: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955692
Once the fix was installed it worked for all 'normal' users and stopped working for 'local admins' running on Win XP.

Anybody had this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar issue with our application. what we did was updating the citrix to PS 4.5 FP1. And changed so that the application doesn't run in seamless mode and used 24bit color for the app in citrix settings.